Debugging MSPaint to find the cause of a crash
mspaint started crashing when I try to save a file 2 seconds after the save file dialog opens, any file, blank canvass directly after opening. Nothing else does this. It is unresponsive but not greyed out for the 2 seconds.
I re-installed it and I can see the default path has changed when save file dialog opens before crashing and it is still crashing so that removes the only thing I thought it could be. I have loaded all symbols for every dll I could find in the call stack while debugging it but there are 5 frames which visual studio tells me are not found in the loaded module nor are they prepended with a module name so I'm at a loss.
Frames before are all normal, frames after are all error throwing/handling related.
What would be the best way to try and figure out the cause of the error?
Error number returned is 0xc0000409 which is STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN and I can't make sense of that in this call stack.


Not really an answer but thoughts for further investigation:
IF the code is not in a loaded module, it's likely on-the-fly generated code. That type of things can be done for many different reasons, though COMToCLRDispatchHelper would suggest the layer converting the historical COM interface to a CLR component needs some generated code for marshalling the parameters from one world to the other.
You can investigate that bit further by introspecting the heap itself, and try to find more information about the allocation that contains the code.
That said, I don't think that's likely to be your culprit. I would rather think the problem is in the one call you didn't find symbols for (mscorlib.ni.dll), which means investigating that is going to be hard.
Without symbols, you're probably stuck with debugging its dissassembly and try to understand what it does by inspection.

Believe it or not that is a .Net dll and I could generate symbols successfully for it using an executable in the Framework64 folder but VS refuses to honour it even though I am generating it from the exact module it is telling me that frame is from, the full path to it. So I gave up on that route. I’m not a C++ guru and definitely not gonna be able for to make sense of assembly. Thanks for your input, much appreciated.
